# Variation of parameters

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I solved the differential equation $y'+ky=e^{rt}$ and found $y=\frac{e^{rt} }{r+k}+\lambda e^{-kt}$, for $r+k\neq0$

But I need to solve the missing case $r=-k$. I was thinking of using the method of variation of parameters but I don't really know how to use it here.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general solution of the homogeneous equation $y'+ky=0$ is
 $$y_h(t)=\lambda e^{-kt}.$$

When $r=-k$, the rhs of the ode belongs to this set. So we can't look for a particular solution of the form $Ae^{-kt}$. In this case, one looks for a particular solution of the form 
$$
y_p(t)=Ate^{-kt}.
$$
Plugging this in the lhs of the ODE yields
$$
-Akte^{-kt}+Ae^{-kt}+Akte^{-kt}=Ae^{-kt}.
$$
So we take $A=1$, and 
$$
y_p(t)=te^{-kt}.
$$

The general solution of the ode is
$$
y(t)=y_h(t)+y_p(t)=\lambda e^{-kt}+te^{-kt}=(\lambda +t)e^{-kt}.
$$

Note: the method to find $y_p$ is known as the [method of undetermined coefficients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_undetermined_coefficients).

You could also solve this first order linear ODE by the [integrating factor method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrating_factor).

The variation of parameter is not bad either, since $y(t)=u(t)e^{-kt}$ is solution if and only if
$$
u'(t)e^{-kt}=e^{-kt}\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad u'(t)=1 \quad\Leftrightarrow\quad u(t)=t+\lambda.
$$
Of course, you get the same result.

Comment: @Carpediem You're welcome. See my edit: I've added a note about the integrating factor method and the variation of parameter.